# Combine the same attribute from different arrays in href (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I’m new to vue.js. I’m building a wizard, but one step I can’t figure out.

I’ve got a checkbox list that outputs the list a user has choosen. So far so good.
In the same array there is an urlAnchor that needs to be combined in the final url.

So for instance, if the user selects extra1 and extra2, the list will be:

**List view** 
Product: Extra 1
Price: 129
URL Anchor: /iii

Product: Extra 2
Price: 49
URL Anchor: /jjj

**URL**
URL needs to be google.com/iii/jjj

But I don’t know how to combine the 2 url anchors in 1 url.

Can someone help me with this please?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- wizard -->
<div id="app">

  <div v-for="(extraItem, index) in extra" v-bind:id="'extraItem-'+extraItem.id" :class="'w-1/2 overflow-hidden my-1 px-1 item-'+index" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="extraCheckboxes" :id="extraItem.name" :value="extraItem.name" v-model="checkedExtras" @click="saveExtra(index)">
    <label class="form-check-label" :for="extraItem.id">{{extraItem.name}}</label>
  </div>

<h1>Output:</h1>

<h2> List view </h2>
          <div v-for="extra in extraOutput">
                <strong>Product:</strong> {{extra.name}} <br />
                <strong>Price:</strong> <span class="items" :data-value="extra.price">{{extra.price}}</span><br />
                URL Anchor: {{extra.urlAnchor}}
           <p>&nbsp;</p>    
          </div>

<h2> URL </h2>
<button><a v-for="extra in extraOutput" :href="'https://google.be'+extra.urlAnchor">Button text</a></button>


</div>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function extras() {
  return [
  { id: 1, name: "Extra 1", price: 129, urlAnchor:"/iii" , selected: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Extra 2", price: 49, urlAnchor:"/jjj" , selected: false },
  { id: 3, name: "Extra 3", price: 59, urlAnchor:"/ggg" , selected: false },
  { id: 4, name: "Extra 4", price: 69, urlAnchor:"/hhh" , selected: false }];

}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      extra: extras(),
      checkedExtras: [],              
      data: [],
    };

  },
  methods: {
    saveExtra: function (index) {
      this.extra[index].selected = !this.extra[index].selected;
    }
 },

  computed: {
      extraOutput: function () {
      let extra = this.extra.filter(function (item) {
        return item.selected === true;
      });
      return extra;
      }
    }

  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already done most of the work with by writing the extraOutput computed.

```js
computed: {
      extraOutput() {
        const anchorsOfSelectedExtras = this.extra
          .filter(extra => extra.selected) //get array of only selected
          .map(extra => extra.urlAnchor); //turn array of objects into array of strings
        return anchorsOfSelectedExtras.join(''); //turn array of strings into one joined string
      }
    }
```

You can also go even shorter:

```js
computed: {
      extraOutput() {
        return this.extra.reduce((accumulator, extra) => extra.selected ? [...accumulator, extra.urlAnchor] : accumulator, []).join('');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't work i'm afraid. It now returns every character on a separated line.

I've selected extra3 and extra 4, output is now:

<h2> URL </h2> 
<a href="/">Text</a>
<a href="g">Text</a>
<a href="g">Text</a>
<a href="g">Text</a>
<a href="/">Text</a>
<a href="h">Text</a>
<a href="h">Text</a>
<a href="h">Text</a>